# URL rewrite for .Net MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have .Net MVC 5 application currently running with url like http://www.example.com in production (Hosted in IIS on Windows server). Now we have requirement to change the URL path to like this http://www.example.com/app.
What will be the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: Would you repurpose `http://www.example.com` for another application? Did you try to move this ASP.NET web app to an IIS application called `app` under this IIS site?

Comment: @LexLi It also required the change in MVC application routing which leads code change in entire application.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a subdirectory `app` in the root directory of your website and move your **.Net MVC 5 application** into the `app` folder, if you set the Default Document, you can directly access it via `http://www .example.com/app` to access.

[image]

In addition, if you just want to access the content of `http://www.example.com` by typing `http://www.example.com/app` in your browser, you can try the following rewrite rule:

```
       <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="test">
                    <match url="app" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.example.com/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Comment: I added folder app under main virtual directory and moved application inside app folder but it is giving me below
 Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Comment: after adding as virtual directory it worked but it didn't find the resources and other controller in code for this I need to change in routeconfig file to alter map route for controllers and everywhere in code need to change the url to append /app

Comment: Routing in MVC is the process of mapping browser requests to controller actions and returning responses. Every MVC application has a default route for the default HomeController. I can set custom routes according to the actual situation.